# Unable to send a file on any of the channels or users without specifying the channel name

Tags: php, curl, slack

While uploading a file on Slack via curl command , is it necessary to specify the channel name ? As I want the command to be used for any of the channels or any of the user names , kindly suggest !

I am using this curl command -

```
curl -F file=@'$filename' -F channels=''-F token='xoxp-*********' 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload'  `
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary no, however it is optional, and supports a list of channel targets.  See here for the documentation on the [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) method.

Comment: Hey , thanks Zach , but if I run this command - curl -F content="Hello" -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload , then it does not return anything on slack :(

Comment: How big is the file in question?  Also, try setting the target at https://yoursubdomain.slack.com/api/files.upload where yoursubdomain is your actual Slack subdomain.

Comment: For now , I am just trying to send 'Hello' via using - curl -F content="Hello" -F token=xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx https://slack.com/api/files.upload , but then Hello does not appear anywhere in the Slack.

Comment: Try adding -v to your curl command, and paste the output (minus the tokens)